# Calculating MD5 digest of empty string without library

Tags: c, md5

I'm trying to learn the MD5 algorithm and writing a c program "from scratch". I want to calculate the MD5 digest of the empty string (and take it on from there).

Documentation (corresponding RFC) seems pretty confusing, but I think I've followed it. I copied the function and constants' definitions (everything up until main()) and the Rounds themselves. My input is just the required padding (since input is the empty string), which is a `1` bit followed by 511 `0` bits (representation of the message should be all `0`'s).

`state[4]` is the buffer array.

I copy my input to an `unsigned long int` array so that it can be treated as integer for the functions, then copy it back to the character array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char *POINTER;
typedef unsigned short int UINT2;
typedef unsigned long int UINT4;

#define S11 7
#define S12 12
#define S13 17
#define S14 22
#define S21 5
#define S22 9
#define S23 14
#define S24 20
#define S31 4
#define S32 11
#define S33 16
#define S34 23
#define S41 6
#define S42 10
#define S43 15
#define S44 21

#define F(x,y,z) ((x & y) | (~x & z))
#define G(x,y,z) ((x & z) | (~z & y))
#define H(x,y,z) (x ^ y ^ z)
#define I(x,y,z) (y ^ (x | ~z))

#define ROTATE_LEFT(x, n) (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32-(n))))

#define FF(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
 (a) += F ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
 (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
 (a) += (b); \
  }
#define GG(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
 (a) += G ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
 (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
 (a) += (b); \
  }
#define HH(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
 (a) += H ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
 (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
 (a) += (b); \
  }
#define II(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
 (a) += I ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
 (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
 (a) += (b); \
  }

int main () {

int i;
char input[64]={0};
char output[64]={0};
unsigned long int x[16]={0};
unsigned long int state[4]={0x67452301, 0xefcdab89, 0x98badcfe, 0x10325476};

//Initialize variables:
int a = state[0];   //A
int b = state[1];   //B
int c = state[2];   //C
int d = state[3];   //D

input[0]=0x80;

memcpy(x, input, 64);

/* Round 1 */
FF (a, b, c, d, x[ 0], S11, 0xd76aa478); /* 1 */
FF (d, a, b, c, x[ 1], S12, 0xe8c7b756); /* 2 */
FF (c, d, a, b, x[ 2], S13, 0x242070db); /* 3 */
FF (b, c, d, a, x[ 3], S14, 0xc1bdceee); /* 4 */
FF (a, b, c, d, x[ 4], S11, 0xf57c0faf); /* 5 */
FF (d, a, b, c, x[ 5], S12, 0x4787c62a); /* 6 */
FF (c, d, a, b, x[ 6], S13, 0xa8304613); /* 7 */
FF (b, c, d, a, x[ 7], S14, 0xfd469501); /* 8 */
FF (a, b, c, d, x[ 8], S11, 0x698098d8); /* 9 */
FF (d, a, b, c, x[ 9], S12, 0x8b44f7af); /* 10 */
FF (c, d, a, b, x[10], S13, 0xffff5bb1); /* 11 */
FF (b, c, d, a, x[11], S14, 0x895cd7be); /* 12 */
FF (a, b, c, d, x[12], S11, 0x6b901122); /* 13 */
FF (d, a, b, c, x[13], S12, 0xfd987193); /* 14 */
FF (c, d, a, b, x[14], S13, 0xa679438e); /* 15 */
FF (b, c, d, a, x[15], S14, 0x49b40821); /* 16 */

/* Round 2 */
GG (a, b, c, d, x[ 1], S21, 0xf61e2562); /* 17 */
GG (d, a, b, c, x[ 6], S22, 0xc040b340); /* 18 */
GG (c, d, a, b, x[11], S23, 0x265e5a51); /* 19 */
GG (b, c, d, a, x[ 0], S24, 0xe9b6c7aa); /* 20 */
GG (a, b, c, d, x[ 5], S21, 0xd62f105d); /* 21 */
GG (d, a, b, c, x[10], S22,  0x2441453); /* 22 */
GG (c, d, a, b, x[15], S23, 0xd8a1e681); /* 23 */
GG (b, c, d, a, x[ 4], S24, 0xe7d3fbc8); /* 24 */
GG (a, b, c, d, x[ 9], S21, 0x21e1cde6); /* 25 */
GG (d, a, b, c, x[14], S22, 0xc33707d6); /* 26 */
GG (c, d, a, b, x[ 3], S23, 0xf4d50d87); /* 27 */
GG (b, c, d, a, x[ 8], S24, 0x455a14ed); /* 28 */
GG (a, b, c, d, x[13], S21, 0xa9e3e905); /* 29 */
GG (d, a, b, c, x[ 2], S22, 0xfcefa3f8); /* 30 */
GG (c, d, a, b, x[ 7], S23, 0x676f02d9); /* 31 */
GG (b, c, d, a, x[12], S24, 0x8d2a4c8a); /* 32 */

/* Round 3 */
HH (a, b, c, d, x[ 5], S31, 0xfffa3942); /* 33 */
HH (d, a, b, c, x[ 8], S32, 0x8771f681); /* 34 */
HH (c, d, a, b, x[11], S33, 0x6d9d6122); /* 35 */
HH (b, c, d, a, x[14], S34, 0xfde5380c); /* 36 */
HH (a, b, c, d, x[ 1], S31, 0xa4beea44); /* 37 */
HH (d, a, b, c, x[ 4], S32, 0x4bdecfa9); /* 38 */
HH (c, d, a, b, x[ 7], S33, 0xf6bb4b60); /* 39 */
HH (b, c, d, a, x[10], S34, 0xbebfbc70); /* 40 */
HH (a, b, c, d, x[13], S31, 0x289b7ec6); /* 41 */
HH (d, a, b, c, x[ 0], S32, 0xeaa127fa); /* 42 */
HH (c, d, a, b, x[ 3], S33, 0xd4ef3085); /* 43 */
HH (b, c, d, a, x[ 6], S34,  0x4881d05); /* 44 */
HH (a, b, c, d, x[ 9], S31, 0xd9d4d039); /* 45 */
HH (d, a, b, c, x[12], S32, 0xe6db99e5); /* 46 */
HH (c, d, a, b, x[15], S33, 0x1fa27cf8); /* 47 */
HH (b, c, d, a, x[ 2], S34, 0xc4ac5665); /* 48 */

/* Round 4 */
II (a, b, c, d, x[ 0], S41, 0xf4292244); /* 49 */
II (d, a, b, c, x[ 7], S42, 0x432aff97); /* 50 */
II (c, d, a, b, x[14], S43, 0xab9423a7); /* 51 */
II (b, c, d, a, x[ 5], S44, 0xfc93a039); /* 52 */
II (a, b, c, d, x[12], S41, 0x655b59c3); /* 53 */
II (d, a, b, c, x[ 3], S42, 0x8f0ccc92); /* 54 */
II (c, d, a, b, x[10], S43, 0xffeff47d); /* 55 */
II (b, c, d, a, x[ 1], S44, 0x85845dd1); /* 56 */
II (a, b, c, d, x[ 8], S41, 0x6fa87e4f); /* 57 */
II (d, a, b, c, x[15], S42, 0xfe2ce6e0); /* 58 */
II (c, d, a, b, x[ 6], S43, 0xa3014314); /* 59 */
II (b, c, d, a, x[13], S44, 0x4e0811a1); /* 60 */
II (a, b, c, d, x[ 4], S41, 0xf7537e82); /* 61 */
II (d, a, b, c, x[11], S42, 0xbd3af235); /* 62 */
II (c, d, a, b, x[ 2], S43, 0x2ad7d2bb); /* 63 */
II (b, c, d, a, x[ 9], S44, 0xeb86d391); /* 64 */

state[0] += a;
state[1] += b;
state[2] += c;
state[3] += d;

memcpy(output, state, 64);

for (i=0;i<=31;i++) {
    printf("%02x ", output[2*i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
ffffff85 ffffff94 58 fffffff9 3f ffffffed ffffff87 ffffffc1 ffffff80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

When it should (conceivably) be the MD5 digest of the empty string

```
d4 1d 8c d9 8f 00 b2 04 e9 80 09 98 ec f8 42 7e
```

Comment: IIRC, a `char` can be signed or unsigned, depending on your compiler/architecture/etc.  In your case, it seems to be signed.  Therefore, if the top bit is set, when you print it out, printf thinks it's a negative number and spits out all the leading 1 bits.  It gets extra confusing because your char will likely be 8 bits long but printf is showing you 32.  The simplest take-home message is use `unsigned char` for this sort of thing or - even better - `#include "inttypes.h"` and use something explicit like `uint8_t`.

Comment: ... in other words the `input` and `output` arrays should be arrays of `unsigned char`. But there is still another problem though.

Comment: With the modifications sugegsted in my previous comment I get this output `85 94 58 f9 3f ed 87 c1 cc cc cc cc 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` and the `cc`s suggests some uninitialized variables or out of range array indexes

Comment: This: `memcpy(x, input, 64)` (and others like it) may well be a big part of your problem.  memcpy deals with bytes not 'types'.  So you're not copying 64 chars to 64 ints, you're copying the first 64 bytes of a char array (which in this case actually _is_ what you want) to the first 64 bytes of an int array (which is _not_ what you want, since each int is likely 4 bytes long).  Try copying with a loop instead, one item at a time.

Comment: EDIT: actually, I read that wrong; you _are_ copying the right amount of data, but you can't necessarily rely on it being copied in the right order, depending on the endianness of your machine.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Me again... You have two memcpy's, one that copies 64 bytes into a 16-element array of long ints and one that copies 64 bytes out of a 4-element array of long ints.  You can therefore reason that _at least_ one of those is wrong!  In this case, the output has to be wrong (unless your machine has 16-byte long ints (hint: it doesn't)) and the input might be wrong (if your machine does not have 4-byte long ints (it might not)).